# Is there any way to represent COLUMN NAME with a Variable in SQL-query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

Is there any way to represent a column name of table with a variable?

Like in below example, in Switch - case: DATE, instead of writing column(visit_date), I want to use variable $d_status.
Thanks in Advance.

```
    $s_id = mysql_prep($s_id);
    $d_status = "visit_date";
    $searchby = mysql_prep($searchby);
    $searchtext = mysql_prep($searchtext);

    $query  = "SELECT * ";
    $query .= "FROM doctor ";
    $query .= "WHERE (s_id = $s_id ) AND (d_status = '{$d_status}') ";

    switch ($searchby){
        case 'd_name':
        $query .= "AND ( d_name = '{$searchtext}' )";
        break;
        case 'd_id':
        $query .= "AND ( d_id = $searchtext )";
        break;
        case 'DATE':
        $query .= "AND ( $d_status = '{$searchtext}' )";
        break;
        Default: null;
        break;
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
        confirm_query($result);
        return $result;
    }
```

Comment: your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP is allowed use a variable for a case value (not often used but allowed) (in others language like c++ not)

```
  $myTets = 'DATE'
  switch ($searchby){
      ....
      case $myTest:
         echo 'Test OK';
         break;
      .....
```

or if you need  a dinamic  column name  contained  in $d_status you can use string concat

```
$query .= "AND ( " . $d_status ." = '{$searchtext}' )";
```

Comment: in the above example case is already used. Can you suggest solution for above example?

Comment: @DarshanSuryawanshi   . explain better what you need .. You are referring to the fact the DATE case is already used ?  . or what .. ?

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy it worked! Can you tell why " . $d_status ." worked and why $d_status din't?

Comment: @DarshanSuryawanshi   work because the string passed  to mysql is already well formed  with all the literal content necessary for its reconition as a table column .. while using the $vars inside  double quote is not used  as column name in sql text string .. hope is clear ..